# convert string text to html tags in php

Tags: php, html

i have sql query like this to use auto complete :

```
SELECT concat(prop_name,', ',prov_name,', ',name,'<br><span class=".$class.">',address,'</span>'),prop_name as value ,4 as orders  FROM v_property
```

And when i loop like this

```
    foreach ($data as $row) {
      $array[]=$row->name;
    }
    header("Content-type:text/x-json");
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Result :

```
Phnom Penh Hotel, Battambang, Cambodia<br><span class=adr>P.O Box 93193, Wat Damnak Village, Sangkat Sala Kamreuk Siem Reap, Cambodia 17107</span>
```

but i want show result with html like this :

```
Phnom Penh Hotel, Battambang, Cambodia
P.O Box 93193, Wat Damnak Village, Sangkat Sala Kamreuk Siem Reap, Cambodia 17107
```

Comment: I guess when you will echo it you will get what you are asking for.or just do `var x=JSON.parse(data);and then $("#divId").html(x);`

Comment: but i use it with autocomplete